# Not able to import ComponentResolver and ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to load a child component dynamically based on some event from the parent component. I am getting some compilation errors in the Import statement and in the ViewChild statements. The following are the [image: errors]

Error# 1

```
import { Component, ComponentResolver, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, } from 'angular2/core';
Error: Module "...node_modules/angular2/core" has no exported member ComponentResolver
```

Error# 2

```
@ViewChild("childContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) childContainer: ViewContainerRef;
Error: Supplied parameters do not  match any signature of call target
```

Error# 3

```
this._cr.resolveComponent(ExtractorDetails).then(cmpFactory => {
    let cmpRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
    cmpRef.instance.QueueID = this.queueID;
});
Error: Property createComponent does not exist on type 'ViewContainerRef'
```

My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"
  }
}
```

My Parent component looks like below
    import { Component, ComponentResolver, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, } from 'angular2/core';
    import { ExtractorDetails } from './ExtractorDetails';
    ..

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kendo-grid',
    templateUrl: './HTML/Admin/KendoGrid.html',
    providers: [Configuration, Constants],
    directives: [Grid]
})
export class ExtractorGrid {
    options: any;
    rowObject: any;
    extractorDetails: any;
    public component: any;
    queueID: number;

    @ViewChild("childContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) childContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private configSetttings: Configuration, private constants: Constants, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private _cr: ComponentResolver) {
        this.setUpGridOptions();
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.rowObject = event.target;

        this._cr.resolveComponent(ExtractorDetails).then(cmpFactory => {
            let cmpRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
            cmpRef.instance.QueueID = this.queueID;
        });
    }

    ....

}
```

Can anyone point me which angular2 version I need to refer if I need to use ComponentResolver and ViewContainerRef?

Comment: I will suggest you to use the new angular2 versions, based on release candidate 3 or even 4. rc4 has been just released https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md (many things are quite different from the beta stage)

Comment: Updated with RC3,  "dependencies": {    "angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",    "angular2":  "2.0.0-rc.3",... }   still getting the same error. any ideas ?

Comment: Did you change the imports from `angular2/xxx` to `@angular/xxx`?

Comment: Where I need to change? Can you please elaborate?  I have changed in the package.json. any other place I have to change it?

Comment: try to go through the angular official tutorials first, doing that might help you in realizing the core/main differences ( for reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html )

Answer (score 0):

ComponentResolver was deprecated and removed. Use ComponentFactoryResolver instead